# Wiring a ceiling pendant UK wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, uk

I've done this before, but maybe because I'm  replacing a ceiling fan with a pendant light the wiring is different.

I have 3 brown wires, with one live
1 Earth (No neutral wire.)
This is the end of the loop. Nothing I can find is dependent on this.

When the switch is on, the power L going to the pendant is 240. When the switch is off there is no power.

I'm just a bit stumped:(

Thanks

Artistic impression of my set up that's not working

[image: circuit]

Comment: You're stuffed without a neutral wire. Are you sure it's not dropped inside the hole?

Comment: And is the terminal marked "LOOP" permanently live?

Comment: One of the Brown wires was the neutral, I switched it to the neutral spot and it's working fine now. Could that be right?

Comment: It's not been wired in accordance with the regulations so all bets are off, frankly. If a brown wire is used as a neutral it should be identified with a bit of blue tape.

Answer (score 2):

One of the brown wires was acting as a neutral, I switched one of the wires into the neutral spot and the light switch is working fine now.

If anyone knows why there is 3 brown wires please let me know. (old wiring?)